# Safari div not clipping enclosed SVG but in chrome it is. How to make them behave consistently?

Tags: css, svg, safari, clipping

I have an SVG with a height of 800px but the bottom half is blank.  I can't edit the SVG or change its height SVG (as that shrinks the content) so I decided to wrap the SVG in a DIV as follows

```
<div class='clippy'>
  <svg height='800' width='1020' ...>
    ...
  </svg>
</div>
```

I've defined the following CSS

```
.clippy {
  height: 360px;
  width: 1020px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

In Chrome this works fine, the div correctly clips the enclosed SVG and the page doesn't scroll.  But in Safari although the div does still visually clip the SVG the page still believes it's the height of the SVG and I am able to scroll the page down.

Is there a way to convince Safari to clip the SVG in the same way Chrome does?

Comment: I don't see why changing its height has to shrink the content. You seem to have imposed unnecessary restrictions which prevent you (or anyone else) coming up with a solution.

Comment: It's a procedurally generated SVG and that's how it appears to work. My clipping solution works fine in chrome but not in safari. That's the issue here.

Comment: Use the DOM to edit it post generation then by changing the height and fixing whatever it is shrinks the content when you do that.

Comment: I've looked at doing that but even setting the SVG height in CSS shrinks the content.

Comment: Add a [mcve] to the question so we can see why.

Comment: Again the issue is not the SVG per-se but the fact that Safari and Chrome are behaving differently.

Comment: Either you want to work around that which I'm trying to help you with, or go fix Safari itself by creating a webkit patch.

Comment: I'll look at extracting an example later tonight.

Comment: So in the process of manually creating an example I experimented with the `viewBox` property of the generated `svg` and solved the root issue I was trying to work-around. So I've raised a PR for the [react-hexgrid](https://github.com/Hellenic/react-hexgrid/pull/4) project which fixes that.  But, SVG issues aside I'd love to know why Safari doesn't behave properly and if there is a workaround.